# Why is my WiFi card unclaimed by drivers in UbuntuMATE?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers

My Realtek 802.11n WiFi card isn't being claimed by the drivers from [here](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=229&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true). I installed led the drivers using the `install.sh` script given in the decompressed `tar.gz`. UbuntuMATE is running on a Raspberry Pi 2.

```
*-usb:4 UNCLAIMED
             description: Generic USB device
             product: 802.11n NIC
             vendor: Realtek
             physical id: 5
             bus info: usb@1:1.5
             version: 2.00
             serial: 00e04c000001
             capabilities: usb-2.10
             configuration: maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

Above is the result of `sudo lshw` in terminal, which shows the unclaimed USB device, the WiFi card.

```
harrycburn@RPi:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

harrycburn@RPi:~$ sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:3a:b4:5a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:542 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:542 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:45957 (45.9 KB)  TX bytes:45957 (45.9 KB)
```

Running `lsusb`:

```
harrycburn@RPi:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `lspci` (I'm not even sure if this is relevant) gives:

```
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method
```

Running `install.sh` gives the error:

```
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/wpa1.conf: time stamp 2012-04-05 03:42:09 is 1333588869.902553677 s in the future
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/wpa1.conf: Cannot change ownership to uid 400, gid 401: Operation not permitted
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl8712_xmit.c
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl8712_xmit.c: time stamp 2012-04-05 03:42:13 is 1333588873.89712326 s in the future
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl8712_xmit.c: Cannot change ownership to uid 400, gid 401: Operation not permitted
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl871x_xmit.c
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl871x_xmit.c: time stamp 2012-04-05 03:42:13 is 1333588873.891775552 s in the future
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit/rtl871x_xmit.c: Cannot change ownership to uid 400, gid 401: Operation not permitted
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit: time stamp 2012-04-05 03:42:13 is 1333588873.890704718 s in the future
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405/xmit: Cannot change ownership to uid 400, gid 401: Operation not permitted
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405: time stamp 2012-04-05 03:42:18 is 1333588878.889988364 s in the future
tar: rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405: Cannot change ownership to uid 400, gid 401: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
rtl8712_8188_8191_8192SU_usb_linux_v2.6.6.0.20120405
Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
bash: make: command not found
Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
bash: make: command not found
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 127
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

As I'm new to Linux in general, I have no idea as to where to go from here, so I'd appreciate any help. If you need any more information, just ask and I'll post it.

Comment: Yea I know this is kinda ironic, but using drivers from hardware manufacture's site is rarely to be a good idea, as the they're usually out-dated like in your case: the latest kernel they support is 3.9, and you're using 3.19 (I guess, pls provide this info). And we also need your card serie (is that `rtl8712`?) And where did you get your driver installation script? Try reinstall `make`, install `build-essential`, `checkinstall` and try again.

Comment: The install script is the one provided in the driver download. Not sure what series, the packaging was really minimalist and of low quality (guess that shoulda' been a warning to me!) It may be `rtl8721`. Running `uname -r` gives `3.18.0-20-rpi2`. The issue with installing from apt-get is that requires internet connection, something I'm trying to get to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just found out that your chip is actually `rtl8192eu`. As far as I know, there is no driver for it in Ubuntu's repo. However, [as v0yAgEr mentioned on OSMC forums](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/tutorial-compiling-a-working-kernel-driver-for-rtl8192eu/5252), there is driver for that chip works for kernel version 3.18 [on GitHub](https://github.com/romcyncynatus/rtl8192eu). I modified v0yAgEr's tutorial to a way hopefully would work for you:

1. Install `build-essential`:

   - From the computer have Internet access, go to [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), download `build-essential`, its dependencies and its dependencies' dependencies to a folder called `bldessen`
   - Copy that folder to your Pi, then install all the debs by `sudo cd bldessen && dkpg --install *.deb`
2. Download the driver from GitHub (click the **Download Zip** button), copy to your Pi, then extract it: `unzip rtl8192eu-master.zip`
3. Compile your driver:

   ```
   cd rtl8192eu-master
   make ARCH=arm
   sudo make ARCH=arm  install
   sudo bash -c 'echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0">/etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf'
   ```
4. Test if the driver loaded:

   ```
   modprobe 8192eu
   modinfo 8192eu
   ```

Comment: Spent a few (3-4) hours installing dependencies. Finally got `make` to work, and got an error when trying to build. I've pasted it [here](http://pastebin.com/9CdgRQL5). Any ideas?

Comment: I've no idea why it failed. But `make install` need to be ran with root permission, i.e. via `sudo` or `su -c`.

Comment: Installed `linux-headers`, compiled fully.

Comment: So @HarryCBurn is your problem solved now? If my answer helpful then I'd be really grateful to see it got accepted.

Comment: Still having , but they're on my end, so I've accepted. Thanks!